# PHP GD resizing transparent image giving black border

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing

I am trying to downsize some transparents images in PHP with GD, and whenever I do, there is a weird black-ish border that is added around it.

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image]

**Code**

```
<?php
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('logo.png'));
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    $newWidth = $width - 1;
    $newHeight = $height - 1;
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecolortransparent($output, imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($output, false);
    imagesavealpha($output, true);
    imagecopyresampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($output);
?>
```

It seems that if I change the code for the new dimensions to be the same as the old (removing the `- 1`), no black borders appear. So the resize is causing the problem.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

*Edit:* I just realized it only happens with [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) and not [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php). However, `imagecopyresampled` gives a far better visual effect and I'd like to make it work if possible.

Comment: Looks like the anti-aliasing is using black for a matte color.

Comment: @Brad indeed it does. However, the documentation page says that anti-aliasing is off by default, and that it only comes with the bundled version of GD, which I'm not using. Maybe some other function is causing it but I don't see any other parameters as far as I can tell...

Comment: I just realized it only happens with [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) and not [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php). However, `imagecopyresampled` gives a far better visual effect and I'd like to make it work if possible.

Comment: @Xeon06 if you find its solution please tell me also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is your source image.

What you have is not a true-color PNG with alpha channel, but an indexed-color PNG with a transparent color.  This is apparent if you open the image in Photoshop:

[image: Image as seen in Photoshop]

This image was created with anti-aliasing already (which gives the yellow text that white-ish border seen here), but when you re-size it, the sub-pixel calculations may go outside of their borders a bit.

I suspect if you fix the image, making it full RGB with an alpha channel, you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you possibly know of any way to make it work programatically or is it undoable?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to get a good source image.  This was easy to fix for you in Photoshop.  E-mail me at brad@musatcha.com, and I will send you the updated file.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. The problem is that this is done by our clients on the web interface. I suppose they'll have to make do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Xeon06, perhaps you can only accept true-color images?  Or, maybe there is a way to convert this image to a full RGB non-indexed image prior to resizing?

Comment: that's what I was wondering about, whether there was a way to convert it beforehand.

Comment: @Xeon06, What if you did `imagecreatefrompng()`, then `imagesavealpha()`, and then immediately `imagepng()`.  No resizing, just open, set alpha saving, and then output?  If you take that output, and then resize, do you get the same issue?  What if you try `imagesavealpha()` on the source image first?

Comment: In both cases I get the same issues.

Comment: @Xeon06, In that case, I suspect that the image will have to be in an okay format ahead of time.  You might be able to script Gimp to do it, but I'd just have a check for true-color image in the first place, and just not accept a file that is an oddball like this.