# Adaptive Images / GD converted tansparent PNG has black border

Tags: image, image-processing, png, gd, responsive-design

I've just recently given [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) a shot.

It seems to be working fine, except when converting transparent PNGs. I have an image that is just a curved white shape on a transparent background. When the image gets converted by Adaptive Images(which I believe uses GD Library for the conversion) the edge of the white shape gets a black border.

Below is a screenshot of the curved edge with the black border so you can see what I mean.

Original size 1920x63: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYmVj.png

[image]

I don't know much about GD Library or how it converts images, but I did do some searching around to see if it was something on my end. I don't think it is though.

I also found [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620462/why-does-this-transparent-png-cause-borders-when-combined-using-gd) in regards to the same issue. However I tried editing Adaptive Images PHP to use the suggested answer by @WouterH but it didn't work. He suggested to create a transparent color and to fill $image with that color before the copy. The code is below:

```
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagealphablending($image, true);
```

In the adaptive-images.php file I found the following lines of code:

```
imagealphablending($dst, false);
imagesavealpha($dst,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($dst, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);
```

This is where I made my changes. I tried numerous variations since I'm not sure what the correct order is, but for the most part tried adapting it to something along these lines:

```
imagesavealpha($dst,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagealphablending($dst, true); 
imagefilledrectangle($dst, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);
```

This didn't seem to make any difference. Depending on the different methods I tried I would either get a black fill for anywhere that was previously transparent, or the same problem would remain (black outline).

Hopefully someone can help me figure this one out... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is the same problem described here:
"What you have is not a true-color PNG with alpha channel, but an indexed-color PNG with a transparent color."
[PHP GD resizing transparent image giving black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141131/php-gd-resizing-transparent-image-giving-black-border)

Comment: I have trouble believing that it has to do with how I saved the file from Photoshop.

I save as PNG-24, transparency is checked. It's as simple as that. 

I just don't understand how no on else aside from [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141131/php-gd-resizing-transparent-image-giving-black-border) and [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620462/why-does-this-transparent-png-cause-borders-when-combined-using-gd) have experienced these problems.

And neither of these threads offer a working solution...